# Linker with overlapping memory definitions

Tags: linker, ld

I made an ld script with the following memory layout:

```
MEMORY
{
  FLASH (rx)  : ORIGIN = 0x00027000, LENGTH = 0xC8000
  RAM   (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x20003FC0, LENGTH = 0x3B040
  RRAM  (rwx) : ORIGIN = 0x2000F000, LENGTH = 0x01000
}
```

As you can see, the RRAM (from 0x2000F000 to 0x2000FFFF) portion overlaps with the RAM portion (from 0x20003FC0 to 0x2002FFF). The code compiles and links with no warnings or errors.

My question is: during normal code execution,.will the system still be able to use the memory from 0x2001000 up to 0x2002FFF? Or does this unusual layout stop the code from using anything after the end of RRAM (unless explicitly allocated to an address)?